# Different accuracy scores with sklearn roc_auc_score on same model using sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model-evaluations, metric, binary-classification

Why do these below lines give different outputs while the input is the same?
I need to report these results in paper, but I am unsure which is better and why.

```
y_pred_list=classifier.predict(X_test)
preds = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
print(y_pred_list[0:10])
print(preds[:,1][0:10])
```

output:

```
[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
[0.7348952  0.9941888  0.4657593  0.00950034 0.5141634  0.504719
 0.55126435 0.8347259  0.6122471  0.5445128 ]
```

Accuracy with `y_pred_list`

```
test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_score=y_pred_list, y_true=y_test)
print(test_auc) # => 0.7003153352913113
```

Accuracy with `preds[:,1]`

```
test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_score=preds[:,1], y_true=y_test)
print(test_auc) # => 0.7823557039988143
```

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between `.predict()` and `.predict_proba()`.

- The former does `argmax(logits)`, where the `logits` are raw class probabilities. Basically a `predict` returns the most probable class label.
- The latter, `predict_proba`, instead, returns the probability that the positive class to occur. That is `logits / logits.sum()`.

Now, the two are interpreted differently by `roc_auc_score` and so you get two different AUCs. Basically, when you call `roc_auc_score(y_score=preds)` the metrics is like thresholding `preds` in multiple ways to get the positive class: `positive = preds > t`. So at each threshold `t`, you get a different TPR (true positive rate) e FPS that, after integration, determine the AUC. In the first case, i.e. `roc_auc_score(y_score=y_pred_list)` the positive class is already determined meaning that `y_pred_list` is insentitive to the threshold `t`.

To conclude, you should use class scores like the probabilities to compute the AUC of either ROC or PR, i.e.: `roc_auc_score(y_score=preds, ...)`. Instead, use `y_pred_list` to compute metrics, like accuracy, that already expect a class label and not a probability nor score.